# How to properly setup VSCode and Wampserver to be able to debug and pause on breakpoint line, using VSCode / PHP XDebug / PHP Debug Extension?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, wampserver

What do I need to do to resolve this issue preventing me from proceeding with debug on VSCode 1.51.0 using xdebug extension on php, along with PHP Debug Extension v 1.13.0 on VS Code by Felix Becker?

**httpd.conf**

```
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 81
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            // Change back to php
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "hostname": "localhost",
            "port": 81,
            "log": true,
            // Deprecated 
            // "localSourceRoot": "/var/www/html/mysite",
            // "serverSourceRoot": "/var/www/html/mysite",
            // server -> local
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            // "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://portaldev/",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Error in Console for Visual Studio - Run as Administrator**

```
  <- outputEvent
    OutputEvent {
      seq: 0,
      type: 'event',
      event: 'output',
      body: {
        category: 'console',
        output: 'Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:81\n' +
          '    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1289:21)\n' +
          '    at listenInCluster (net.js:1354:12)\n' +
          '    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1493:7)\n' +
          '    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:65:10) {\n' +
          "  code: 'EACCES',\n" +
          "  errno: 'EACCES',\n" +
          "  syscall: 'listen',\n" +
          "  address: '127.0.0.1',\n" +
          '  port: 81\n' +
          '}\n'
      }
    }
    Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:81
        at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1289:21)
        at listenInCluster (net.js:1354:12)
        at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1493:7)
        at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:65:10) {
      code: 'EACCES',
      errno: 'EACCES',
      syscall: 'listen',
      address: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 81
    }
    <- launchResponse
    Response {
      seq: 0,
      type: 'response',
      request_seq: 2,
      command: 'launch',
      success: false,
      message: 'listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:81',
      body: {
        error: {
          id: 0,
          format: 'listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:81',
          showUser: true
        }
      }
    }
```

---

Wampserver Configuration Settings
**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:81>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


#
<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerName portaldev
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/portaldev"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/portaldev/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#
<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerName portallive
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/liveportal"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/liveportal/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please check Xdebug documentation on what Xdebug port is and how it all works. In short: 1) it's Xdebug that connects to debug client (VSCode in your code) and NOT other way around 2) Xdebug port has to be DIFFERENT to your website port. `"port": 81,` is just wrong here -- you cannot tell VSCode to listen on port 81 when your Apache is already using it. It has to be the same port that you have in php.ini

Comment: @LazyOne, thanks for the hint,  I am posting a complete answer to my question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem and got my application to stop at the specified breakpoint in my application.

After noting the suggestions in the first comment from the original question, I changed my XDebug **broadcast port** to **9000** in **php.ini** and set and set my **launch configuration json** file to **listen to** **9000** in my project directory, and set my **php.ini** `xdebug.remote_port = "9000"`, and `xdebug.remote_mode = "req"`.  Then set my **listen port** to **80** in **httpd.conf** and all **virtual host ports** to **80** in **httpd-vhosts.conf**.

After launching my browser, I started up the debugger by going to VS Code, clicking and clicking on (**Run**, then **Debug** (or pressing **F5** on the keyboard), the IDE stopped at the breakpoint set originally (which was done by clicking to the left of the source code line number and observing a **bright red circle or dot appearing as a breakpoint**.

*A light grey but hollow circle, or a light red, or pink circle was not the correct breakpoint for my test to debug.*

**httpd.conf**

```
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80     <------------- Changed to 80 instead of 81
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [ 
        {
            "name": "Listen For XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "port": 9000,  <----- Modified to default XDebug port 9000
            "request": "launch",
            "pathMappings": {
                "c:/wamp64/www/portaldev/": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
# Virtual Hosts

<VirtualHost *:80>    <------ Set to port 80
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


#
<VirtualHost *:80>   <------ Set to port 80
    ServerName portaldev
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/portaldev"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/portaldev/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#
<VirtualHost *:80>    <------ Set to port 80
    ServerName portallive
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/liveportal"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/liveportal/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**php.ini**

```
; XDEBUG Extension
[xdebug]
zend_extension="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.3.12/ext/php_xdebug-2.9.8-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_mode = "req"         <------ Added to make the setup work
xdebug.remote_port = "9000"        <------ Set to 9000
xdebug.remote_log = "c:/wamp64/tmp/log"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

Comment: You could have kept the `81` for Apache -- it's fine (but yes, 80 is the default so it;s more convenient as you do not have to explicitly declare it as part of the URL). It's Xdebug port that has to be different. By default it's 9000 and it may conflict with `php-fpm` that you may also have installed on your system (on Linux/Mac though, not on Windows). Upcoming Xdebug 3 will use 9003 by default.

Answer (score 0):

php 7.3.5 WAMP

In my case i had to use the following:

```
zend_extension="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.3.5/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.7.2-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = Off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

and

```
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen For XDebug",
      "type": "php",
      "port": 9000,
      "request": "launch"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Hey Khalifa,  thank you so much for your response, can you highlight where or what line the provided solution diverges from the provided solution?  Thank you.

Comment: The profiler and pathMappings settings.

Comment: Ok,  so profiler is not a dependency to get a working solution.  I consider it useful but not required to establish a correct debug session.