# Xdebug + VSCode + PHP + WampServer : breakpoint not hit on start of debug session

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, wampserver

A while back I succeeded at resolving this problem:

[How to properly setup VSCode and Wampserver to be able to debug and pause on breakpoint line, using VSCode / PHP XDebug / PHP Debug Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64793446/how-to-properly-setup-vscode-and-wampserver-to-be-able-to-debug-and-pause-on-bre)

Now I have PHP 8 with the latest VSCode and Xdebug 3, but my breakpoint is not hit in my API, which runs with a custom host name renamed from `localhost` (virtual host) in back of a Node.js ReactJS app (on `riskaim:3000`, where as the PHP API server is running on `riskaim:9003`)

I can't get the VSCode debugger to stop on the line on which I have set a breakpoint.

How do I resolve this?

Here are my settings:

Bottom of php.ini
c:/wamp64/bin/apache/php/apache2.4.46/bin/php.ini

```
; XDEBUG Extension
[xdebug]
zend_extension="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.0.9/ext/php_xdebug-3.0.4-8.0-vs16-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_mode = "req" 
xdebug.mode = debug       
xdebug.client_port = "9003"
xdebug.remote_log = "c:/wamp64/tmp/log"
xdebug.show_local_vars = 0
xdebug.idekey = vsc
```

settings.json

```
{
    "php.executablePath": "C:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.0.9/php.exe",
}
```

launch.json

```
 {
        // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
        // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
        // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [        
            {
                "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
                "type": "php",
                "request": "launch",
                "port": 9003
            }
        ]
    }
```

Middle of httpd.conf

```
#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 9003
```

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
# Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:9003>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>




<VirtualHost *:9003>
    ServerName riskaim
    DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/RiskAIM/"
    <Directory  "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/RiskAIM/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: 1) Your php.ini uses Xdebug v2 params while you are using Xdebug v3. Go through https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide and update your Xdebug config accordingly. 2) Xdebug port (`client_port`) is for Xdebug connection ONLY. You cannot use that port to run your web server / some service. Only debug client (VSCode in your case) must be listening on that port). RTM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had added an unnecessary line in my `.htaccess` file of my api folder.  Removal of this line fixed the problem and the debugger step cursor started working successfully.

Changes made

.htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex api.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}=80            <-------------- I removed this line and it the debugger started stepping through the code on my first api get request
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/api.php?requestPath=$1 [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 403  "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=//riskaim:3000' />"
ErrorDocument 404  "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=//riskaim:3000' />"
```

Bottom of php.ini (c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.46/bin/php.ini)

```
   [xdebug]
    zend_extension="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.0.9/zend_ext/php_xdebug-3.0.4-8.0-vs16-x86_64.dll"
    xdebug.mode = develop,debug
    xdebug.start_with_request = yes
    xdebug.client_host = localhost
    xdebug.client_port = "9003"
    xdebug.idekey = vsc
```

launch.json

```
 {
        // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
        // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
        // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [        
            {
                "name": "Launch Chrome",
                "request": "launch",
                "type": "chrome",
                "url": "http://riskaim:3000",
                "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },      
            {
                "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
                "type": "php",
                "request": "launch",
                "port": 9003,
                "hostname": "riskaim",
                "pathMappings": {
                    "c:\\wamp64\\www\\riskaim": "${workspaceRoot}"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

httpd.conf Middle of file

```
Listen 80  <------------ changed from Listen 9003 (incorrect)
```

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>   <----------------changed from *:9003
    ServerName riskaim
    DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/RiskAIM/"
    <Directory  "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/RiskAIM/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```